# Python argument passing overhead and object reference

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I've built a couple threaded server projects with Python, and synchronization is always an annoying worry to address.

Often times when work is passed from thread to another there is a need to find associated objects and information from data structures that are accessed from multiple threads. Synchronization with locks etc is the canonical approach but it is often hard to have any certainty that your synchronization is in fact accurate. This could be circumvented by carrying associated objects along the processing pipeline even where they are not needed.

As these are usually object references, how much would it increase overhead? By all logic it shouldn't really, so is this a common practice?

Comment: *passed from thread to another*.Do you used ``global``?Or OOPs?

Answer (score 0):

This question would be easier to answer with more context. But in general, there's no appreciable time cost to passing a few object references in the job payload. The amount of memory overhead associated with each OS thread is probably greater than all of the memory consumed by thread-local references. The main risk is that holding needless references will prevent garbage collection from occurring, but this would also happen if you stored these objects in a global data structure.

> Synchronization with locks etc is the canonical approach but it is often hard to have any certainty that your synchronization is in fact accurate.

Making sure a single data structure is free from data races is usually easy with locks. You just need to wrap every read and write operation with a lock-unlock call. Though this will decrease performance under contention, which will make thread-local storage even faster in comparison.

As long as you aren't making deep copies of huge data structures for every single thread, you'll be fine. Keeping job context in thread-local storage where it can be accessed without contention against other threads is usually encouraged.